# Keeping keras loaded for evaluation

Tags: java, python, keras

I'm trying to get my python application which utilizes keras/tfgpu to make predictions based on images and return the predictions to a JavaFX application however the load time for the tensorflow backend is quite high compared to the networks evaluation methods so the app feels very slow.

I'd do something with networking however it seems a bit overkill seeing as how the apps will always be on the same machine and I don't necessarily want to deal with that whole process. What are the common methods for dealing with this kind of situation?

Comment: Have a look at PyRO. It should be able to do what you want

Comment: Is there perhaps a standard library method that works, I already have to many dependencies

Comment: Not as far as I know.

Comment: Actually, you could try using iPython and the JuPyTer notebook (or other iPython notebooks). That might be the right solution for you!